# Fetch all rows that meet criteria and display in new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate excel so that it allows me to show all records from another tab where a certain condition is met.

my source table is(Analysis tab):
[image]

I have name all my ranges according to the column name. so for example named range `Vehicle` is 
`=Analysis!$A$2:$A$3000`

all ranges go to row 3000.

dropdown is cell C1, the name of the vehicle and the filter to use.

My destination worksheet is as follows:
[image]

In Cell B3, I have the following array formula that I have tried to adapt unsuccessfully.
`=IF(COUNTIF(vehicle,DropDown)<ROWS($A$1:$A1),"",INDEX(DataTable,LARGE(IF(DropDown=Litres,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(vehicle)))),ROW(Analysis!$A1)),MATCH(Analysis!A$3,Analysis!$A$3:$E$3,0)))`

This does not work correctly. Any help is appreciated.

to summarize, I want to return all rows from Tab analysis where vehicle is equal to cell C1. I need to automate this as data changes each day.

**UPDATE**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use VBA. A good way to do this is by adding a custom function and then using it in another cell. For instance in cell D1 put `=MyFunction(C1)`. Then create a module in VBA and add the following (May contain some bugs cause I didn't test it):

```
Function MyFunction(parVal As String) As String
    'Clear what is there now
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3", "I3000").ClearContents

    'Add new rows
    varRange = Sheets("Analysis").UsedRange
    varCount = 2
    For varRow = 1 To varRange.Rows.Count
        If varRange(varRow, 1) = parVal Then
            varRange(varRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
            varCount = varCount + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(varCount, 1).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next varRow
    MyFunction = "Found " & (varCount - 2) & " rows"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks neelsg. used yoru code in the module section of vba. error in D1 is now `#name?`. I have added an image of my changes to the code. please advise if you have some ideas of what I am doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: That means it does not find the function. First change `Function My...` to `Public Function My...` and also save the file as a Macro-Enabled workbook (`.xlsm` instead of `.xlsx`)

Answer (score 1):

Additional info from: http://www.cpearson.com

Where To Put The Code

The code for a UDF should be placed in a standard code module, not one of the Sheet modules and not in the ThisWorkbook module. In the VBA editor, go to the Insert menu and choose Module. This will insert a new code module into the project. A module can contain any number functions, so you can put many functions into a single code module. You can change the name of a module from Module1 to something more meaningful by pressing the F4 key to display the Properties window and changing the Name property to whatever you want.

You can call a function from the same workbook by using just the function name. For example:

=RectangleArea(12,34)